# How to copy qemu raw images?

Tags: backup, kvm, qemu

I want to backup kvm virtual machines and copy machine's images another path or usb disk? How to copy " qemu raw images"?

Comment: Do you use libvirt-based solutions like virt-manager or do you call kvm directly?

Comment: Do you want to backup a copy while the virtual machine is running or can you shutdown the VM for the backup?

Comment: I dont use libvirt or virt-manager and I can shutdown vm  for the backup.Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Copy kvm virtual machines is not complicated: First, you need to shutdown the virtual machine, then you need to find the disk image where the virtual machine is stored and finally copy it to another place (`cp /path/to/disk_image /new_path/`).

If the virtual machine is stored on its own partition, use `dd if=/dev/PARTITION of=/path/to/backup/backup.img bs=1M` or use `ddrescue /dev/PARTITION /path/to/backup/backup.img`.

The virtual machine images could be stored in different formats. Usually, the `qcow2`-format is used. To get the `raw` format, you can use `qemu-img convert`.

Comment: Note: you don't need to shutdown, you can suspend it, do the copy and resume it. That's what [proxmox](http://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Main_Page) do, for instance.

Comment: I made it(shutdown and cp /path/to/disk_image /new_path/) already.But the file sizes are different.Why different?

Comment: How did you check the file sizes? BTW, there are also checksum programs like `sha1sum` or `md5sum`.

Comment: orginal image : du -h ==>> 15G clone file: du -h ==>> 9,6G.I didn't check md5sum or sha1sum .

Comment: du returns the used space on the file system. For sparse files this is different from the (real) file size. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file for more information.

Answer (score 2):

`cp` is enough for most files. If you prefer to use qemu's utilities, you can `qemu-img convert` with input and output formats both being raw

Answer (score 0):

Disks copying i.e. raw images, can be (and should be) done by using

```
qemu dd if=source of=source
```

Also other options `bs`, `count`, `skip` are usable in the same manner as it is in real `dd` cmd.

Raw images usually do not take full size of disk space if it is not necessary.

If you make regular copy of the image it will occupy full size on the destination disk.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: man qemu-img does not mention anywhere that dd properly handles holes or deals with preallocation=falloc or similar. So to be safe on better always use convert.